# Grails constraint: unique between attributes values

Tags: grails, constraints, unique-constraint

I'm trying to add a constraint to check that two attributes have different values.

Here is my case:

```
class Game {
  static belongsTo = [ Team ]

  Team teamHome
  Team teamAway
}
```

What I'm trying to do is somenthig like:

```
static constraints = {
  teamHome( notEqual: teamAway )
  teamAway( notEqual: teamHome )
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`validator` constraint](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html):

```
static constraints = {
  teamHome validator: { val, obj ->
    val != obj.teamAway
  }
}
```

The `val` argument is the `teamHome` value, and `obj` is the object that is being validated, through which you can access the `teamAway` property.